# Configure htaccess to serve static django files

Tags: python, django, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having trouble setting up Apache to serve static Django files.  I am on a shared host and don't have access to the Apache config files.  All the examples use `Alias` in the Apache config files, so I'm trying to figure out how to do it with mod_rewrite in .htaccess.

**My setup.py looks like this:**

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home2/usr/public_html/mydjangoproject/static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I ran `python manage.py collectstatic` in the terminal and it did its thing, so that now I have a folder under `/public_html/mydjangoproject/static` which currently has the subfolder `admin` and its content.

Now I am trying to configure apache to just serve the static files rather than going through mod_wsgi, as it says in the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files):

> We strongly recommend using django.contrib.staticfiles to handle the
>   admin files (along with a Web server as outlined in the previous
>   section; this means using the collectstatic management command to
>   collect the static files in STATIC_ROOT, **and then configuring your Web
>   server to serve STATIC_ROOT at STATIC_URL**)

To do this, I added line 3 in the .htaccess file as shown below. This file is at `/home2/usr/public_html/mydjangoproject/.htaccess`

**My .htaccess file:**

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /static/ /home2/usr/public_html/mydjangoproject/static
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mysite.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Note that I tried line 3 with and without the trailing slash, to no effect.

When I go to www.mysite.com/mydjangoproject/static/ I receive a 500 Internal Server Error.  Likewise, the admin page is still not getting the css files it needs.  What's going on?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, after a whole day of messing with .htaccess regexes (yukk!), I finally figured out the problem.

It actually has nothing to do with the .htaccess file.  The problem was in my **settings.py** `STATIC_URL`.  Turns out I had to set `STATIC_URL = '/mydjangoproject/static/'` in order to mesh with the `STATIC_ROOT = '/home2/usr/public_html/mydjangoproject/static'` I was using.

So the lesson here is that if you put your static files anywhere other than in the Apache DocumentRoot (`/home2/usr/public_html/` in my case) you have to set the `STATIC_URL` in **settings.py** accordingly, rather than using the default `/static/`.

Hope this helps some poor soul from enduring what I did!

Comment: That last line was the answer! I've been hit with 403 forbiddens and went into a rabbit hole trying to fix permissions and apache configs. Turns out just make sure to change STATIC_URL from default.